Sequence coverage using R
I have a protein sequence with 100 aminoacids (AA) that can be handled as a data.frame. Each AA has a position and for now all that matters is the position:
Protein <- data.frame(AA = 1:100)
Than I have a data.frame with peptides from the protein (after digestion / sequence breakdown) with Initial and Final position of the AA related to the protein:
df <- data.frame(
Peptides = c("Peptide_A", "Peptide_B", "Peptide_C", "Peptide_D"), 
Initial.AA = c(1, 23, 59, 77), 
Final.AA = c(18, 58, 70, 100)
)

Output:

   Peptides Initial.AA Final.AA
1 Peptide_A          1       18
2 Peptide_B         23       58
3 Peptide_C         59       70
4 Peptide_D         77      100


Inspecting df it´s clear that some AA were not mapped (19:22 and 71:76, total of 10 unmapped AA).
I would like the have as output the total percentual of mapped AA, which in this example is 90% (90 mapped AA from all the peptides / 100 protein AA).
All answers are welcome as always, but tidyverse ones are prefered.

Thanks to all that replied and commented. I will keep Andre´s solution as it is easier to explain to may lab colleagues, but baldurs and Capitains solutions work as well. As usually we only have hundreds of peptides to map, computation power is not a bottleneck in this case.

A base R approach using setdiff
(1 - length(setdiff(
       Protein$AA, 
       unlist(apply(df[,2:3], 1, \(x) 
                seq(x["Initial.AA"], x["Final.AA"]))))) / nrow(Protein)) * 100
[1] 90

A dplyr alternative may be
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  reframe(AA = seq(Initial.AA, Final.AA)) %>% 
  summarize(total_mapped_AA = (1 - length(setdiff(Protein$AA, AA)) / 
    nrow(Protein)) * 100)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  total_mapped_AA
            <dbl>
1              90


@s_baldur Right, thanks for pointing that out! Gonna add! Had that before editing but somehowit was lost in editing!

Thanks for your solution Andre, it works for me. I will keep yours as it will be easier to explain to my lab colleagues.

First I added a new column and used the lag function to get the differences between Initial.AA and Final.AA. Lag takes the row before as input. Notice that we have one NA, thats because there is no row before the first one. We can set default = 1, to avoid this)
df<- df%>%mutate(newcol = Initial.AA - lag(Final.AA, default = 0) -1)
> df
   Peptides Initial.AA Final.AA newcol
1 Peptide_A          1       18      0
2 Peptide_B         23       58      4
3 Peptide_C         59       70      0
4 Peptide_D         77      100      6

Then I calculate the percentage. In this case we get 90%
Protein <- data.frame(AA = 1:100)
1- sum(df$newcol, na.rm = TRUE)/NROW(Protein)
[1] 0.9


With default = 0 in your lag() call, you can avoid the NA issue all together.  What about if the final peptide doesn't finish at 100?

Thank you for your reply pbraeutigm. However, as PSGA raised, not always the last peptide will end with the 100 AA.

Have you tried my solution? I am calculating a percentage, it should work with any number of Peptides, or not?

This solution should work even when df$Initial.AA does not start at 1:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- 
  rowwise(df) |> 
  mutate(seq = list(seq(Initial.AA, Final.AA, by = 1))) |> 
  unnest(seq)

1 - sum(!Protein$AA %in% df$seq)/length(Protein$AA)
#> [1] 0.9

Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0

You might put Protein <- data.frame(AA = 1:100) back in there for future clarity.

Brute force in base R:
1 - length(setdiff(Protein$AA, unlist(Map(":", df$Initial.AA, df$Final.AA)))) / nrow(Protein)

# [1] 0.9


Thanks s_baldur, that's the sort of solution that makes me want to dive deeper in Base R. The solution works for me.
